# A question about the regular condition of line integral

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Gamma\colon \mathbf{r}(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t)),a\leq t\leq b$ be a curve and $x(t),y(t),z(t)$ are continuous differentiable functions and let $f: U \to \mathbb R$ be a scalar field where $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$. In many books, in order to compute the line integral of $f$ along $\Gamma$:
$$\int_\Gamma fds,$$
they use the formula
$$\int_{\Gamma} f(\mathbf{r})\, ds = \int_a^b f\left(\mathbf{r}(t)\right) \left|\mathbf{r}'(t)\right| \, dt.$$
but these books often add the regular condition: $x(t)'^2+y(t)'^2+z(t)'^2\neq 0$.

I think this condition is superfluous. Am I right？

If $x(t)'^2+y(t)'^2+z(t)'^2=0$ at finite or countable points, I think the above integral formula is also correct.

My Question is: Is the above formula correct as long as $x(t),y(t),z(t)$ are continuous differentiable functions?

Comment: If your sole concern is defining the value of this integration, then yes, the regularity condition serves no purpose. even when $\mathbf r' = 0$ at uncountably many points (for example, the path of a person who stopped to rest awhile). However, there are many theorems about line integrals where irregular curves cause issues in other fashions. Rather than add regularity conditions to those other theorems, some authors choose to simply outlaw irregular curves at the start, since they are rarely useful and easily handled when they do occur.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Could you give me some nontrivial examples which irregular curves cause issues in other fashions?

Comment: Go look up theorems involving line integrals. Decide for yourself whether they are still applicable for irregular curves. I have better things to do with my time than to spend hours researching to satisfy some stranger's idle curiousity.